# « À l’unité de soins psychiatriques », « sur l’unité de soins psychiatriques » ou « dans l’unité de soins psychiatriques »

Tags: choix-de-mot, prépositions

Exemple 1:

Il y a dix agents qui assurent la sécurité

…à l’unité de soins psychiatriques.

…sur l’unité de soins psychiatriques.

…dans l’unité de soins psychiatriques.

Exemple 2:

Il y a trois médecins de garde

…à l’unité psychiatrique.

…sur l’unité psychiatrique.

…dans l’unité psychiatrique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exemple 1, *none of the above*¹ comme on dit. Le plus idiomatique serait :

> Il y a dix agents qui assurent la sécurité **de** l’unité de soins psychiatriques.

Exemple 2, ***à*** et ***dans*** sont équivalents, ***sur*** est plus qu'improbable.

¹ J'exagère, ***à*** et ***dans*** sont possibles, ***sur*** est beaucoup plus inattendu mais pourrait éventuellement s'entendre dans un contexte de jargon professionnel.

Answer (score 0):

On peut éliminer « sur » ;  « à » et « dans » conviennent toutes les deux.

On utiliserait « sur » pour les routes, les passages pour piétons, les chantiers, pour certains noms (« lieux », par exemple).